# Spring MVC - JSON response - How to prevent

Tags: json, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a look-ahead form field that searches for people records based on the first name and lastname form fields.. Fields are posted by Jquery and The person list is returned as JSON and results are displayed as a table. Post request is submitted for every keyup event. But I am having an issue with this.

Lets say, user entered 'a' in firstname field. The request is submitted as ajax call. Then user enters 'b' in the field. Now the request is again submitted with 'ab' as firstname. Issue is that, 'ab' has less number of results so the results are displayed instantly. Since 'a' has more results it takes some time to process and build the results table and once it is done building the table, it replaces the existing table for 'ab'. This is not the behavior I want as 'a' was the first request and 'ab' was the latest request, it shouldn't be displaced. So how do I prevent results from old request displacing new results. Thanks in advance!

---Update---

controller method is something like..

```
 public @ResponseBody List<PSPerson> getPersonsWithNames(
        @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName) 
{

    Map<String, String> attrMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    attrMap.put("firstName", firstName);
    attrMap.put("lastName", lastName);

    return personService.getPeople(attrMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a timestamp to your returned Json values. And in your jquery compare the latest timestamp received to the actual.

Comment: thanks for the reply WarfarA.. JSON response is a list of Person objects. how do I add an extra variable to this response?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the look-ahead/autocomplete forms that you see on the web have a "threshold count" of characters (e.g. in *PengoWorks jQuery Autocomplete* it's `minChars`, ).
If you're using that jQuery plugin you can also use the `delay` option to specify the number of milliseconds to wait before sending the AJAX request.

If you use a typical `minChars` value such as `3`, plus a reasonable `delay` value of perhaps 100ms, you will probably have "narrowed down" the search space enough to not have any problems with one resultset "overtaking" another.

You can try playing with these values [here](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html).

Edit: The same options are available in *[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)* - they are called `minLength` and `delay`.